# Azure CLI + using oAuth token

Tags: azure-devops, release

All,

I'm trying to use oAuth token in Azure-CLI to access VSTS git to get commit details, but it is not working. Though the same works well with Azure-Powershell task. Tried multiple combo's but none work. Any info/help is appreciated.

Combo 1. Pass System.AccessToken as a parameter and use it in Header (-H of curl to Authorization: Bearer ${1}
Combo 2: Pass System.AccessToken as a parameter and use it in Header (-H of curl to Authorization: Bearer $1
Combo 3: Directly use the variable in -H viz. Authorization: Bearer $(SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)

I also tried to save the $1 parameter to a variable viz. x=$1 and use $x, but it errors out as "'x' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: How do you get commit details through Azure CLI? What's the detail code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows agent (e.g. Hosted VS2017 agent), using `%SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%` instead.

If you are using linux agent, using `$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` instead.